# Google Maps API V2 Throwing Error

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

I am getting a Error 08-23 13:27:35.790:
 W/dalvikvm(1608): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 184: Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;.setLocalOnly (Z)Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;

All keys , Google Play Libraries etc are ok , but throwing error in emulator .

```html
08-23 13:27:36.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1608): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-23 13:27:36.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1608): Process: ca.sfu.cmpt276.bfraser, PID: 1608
08-23 13:27:36.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1608): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ca.sfu.cmpt276.bfraser/ca.sfu.cmpt276.bfraser.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class fragment
08-23 13:27:36.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
08-23 13:27:36.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
08-23 13:27:36.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
08-23 13:27:36.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
08-23 13:27:36.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-23 13:27:36.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-23 13:27:36.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
08-23 13:27:36.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-23 13:27:36.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-23 13:27:36.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-23 13:27:36.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-23 13:27:36.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-23 13:27:36.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1608): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class fragment
08-23 13:27:36.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:714)
08-23 13:27:36.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756)
08-23 13:27:36.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
08-23 13:27:36.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
08-23 13:27:36.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
08-23 13:27:36.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
08-23 13:27:36.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
08-23 13:27:36.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):  at ca.sfu.cmpt276.bfraser.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
08-23 13:27:36.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
08-23 13:27:36.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-23 13:27:36.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
08-23 13:27:36.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):  ... 11 more
08-23 13:27:36.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1608): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 7895000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
08-23 13:27:36.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):  at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzad(Unknown Source)
08-23 13:27:36.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):  at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
08-23 13:27:36.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzy.zzaG(Unknown Source)
08-23 13:27:36.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzy.zzaF(Unknown Source)
08-23 13:27:36.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
08-23 13:27:36.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$zzb.zzwP(Unknown Source)
08-23 13:27:36.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$zzb.zza(Unknown Source)
08-23 13:27:36.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):  at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
08-23 13:27:36.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):  at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onInflate(Unknown Source)
08-23 13:27:36.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
08-23 13:27:36.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):  at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4785)
08-23 13:27:36.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:690)
08-23 13:27:36.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):  ... 21 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Google Maps, you need to add Play services version. Add following declaration within the `<application>` element:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Comment: Why is it needed? Also, what should I do for the others? I use com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.0.0 and com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.0.0 , and I have a very similar error (but only when running on release mode)